# Apps opening under another icon in Dock

Tags: ubuntu-dock

I am using Ubuntu with [Studio 3t](https://studio3t.com/free/) even tho I can "pin" an icon to start it in the Ubuntu dock, when it opens, it opens under another icon. Why is that? Isit possible to make it open under its own icon?

[image]

Comment: This is because the window class of the running window does not match the window class the system expects.